# Woocommerce Footer not Aligning to FullScreen

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have recently developed my first woocommerce site and I have had some niggling issues that I am trying to fix.

The site itself can be viewed at http://www.dcsreceivers.co.uk/.

The problem I currently have is with the footer bar as the background behind it does not display edge to edge on different screen sizes. When I developed this on my laptop (screen size 13), this was fine but when I have viewed this on bigger screens this leaves a gap on the right hand side and I'm not sure how to how to fix it.

The code that is used for this is:

```css
#colophon .site-info { 
    background-color: #2c2c2c; 
    margin-left: -500px; 
    padding-left: 500px; 
    margin-right: -46px; 
    padding-right: 500px; 
    border-top: 1px solid #3A3A3A;
}
```

Would appreciate it if somebody could advise on how to fix this as I would like to display correctly on all screen sizes.

Thanks in advance.

Image attached to show issue[image]

Comment: Can you post an image to let us better understand the problem?

Comment: RHShanks92, thanks for your response. Attach image as required.

Comment: As soon as possible I look for the solution

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities. You may want to have your black bar in the footer to:

- expand to fit the width of the **screen**;
- fit the width of the **content** above it, not the width of the screen.

To achieve the first aim, you can put the `.site-info` div **outside** of its container, the div with class `col-full`. In this case the code will be:

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" ...>
   <div class="col-full">
      ...
   </div>
   <div class="site-info">
      ...
   </div>
</footer>
```

In this case, however, you have to accordingly set the padding of the `.site-info` div to adjust the position of its content.

To achieve the second aim, you can simply remove the margin:

```
#colophon .site-info { 
   background-color: #2c2c2c; 
   padding-left: 500px; 
   padding-right: 500px; 
   border-top: 1px solid #3A3A3A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

remove the margins.

Comment: Thank you guys, Jen will try that and let you know how i get on.